# Why both options were enabled in first post review at today's morning?

Tags: support, bug, first-post-review

I have seen a peculiar thing while reviewing first post at today's morning.

[image]

Could you observe something different?

Ow, `No Action Needed` and `I'm Done`, both the options were enabled simultaneously!

Is this as usual?

I think not. Because I had never seen  such type of scenario before.

Could anyone tell me what happened actually?

Comment: Also consider taking more time in reviews, some of them have taken you only 2 seconds, if I am seeing things right.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Catching review is a challenging thing now a days. So, usually, I catch all the reviews available and then I review them and then I release them altogether. Thats why you are seeing such type of time gap.

Comment: In which case, let others do it as well, as you pretty much stated, you are not the only reviewer, don't keep them all to yourself

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Everyone should oil his own machine. However, it is totally off-topic, relative to the question. If you have any question regarding the question, feel free to ask or discuss. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

You already actioned on the post by the time you saw it in review, maybe that comment upvote, or a flag. In those cases the review system gets confused, since you just reached the post by review and haven't done anything, but a query to the database shows that you have done something already... or something like that.

Comment: No, I up flagged the comment while reviewing to observe its behavior. And in cases where I took action before, the `I'm Done` option remains enabled. Sometimes, it takes a few moment to switch between the options, but I never saw two having enabled simultaneously.

Comment: "Up flagged"..?

Comment: @manetsus well, thats the only way I've been able to reproduce it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oh, typo! I think you could understand what I mean actually!